# can i use the code from one class (constructor + methods) in another class? (java)

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, redundancy

I'm making a game and I'm trying to ged rid of all the redundancy in my code. All my panels(`PlayPanel`, `HighScore`, `Quit`,..) have a lot of properties in common so i made a class `IPanel` to extend in all my panels. it looks like this:

```
package menu;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class IPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public Image achtergrond;
    public Tanks mainVenster;

    public String backgroundPath; 



    public IPanel(String backgroundPath, Tanks mainVenster)
    {    
        super();
        this.mainVenster = mainVenster;
        this.setLayout(null);

        this.backgroundPath = backgroundPath;
        achtergrond = new     //achtergrond is dutch for background
            ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(backgroundPath)).getImage();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(achtergrond, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), 
                this);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        mainVenster.switchPanel();
    }

    public void switchPanel(Tanks toActivate)
    {
        remove(mainVenster);
        mainVenster = toActivate;
        add(mainVenster);   //this is wrong, no idea what to do actually

        validate();
        repaint(); 
    }

    }
```

I'm able to use the constructor in other classes, but i don't know how to use the 
`paintComponent` and `actionPerformed` *methods in other classes*. I use these 2 methods in all of my Panels so i think it's unnecessary to write the methods all over again for all these panels.

an example of one of my panels is `QuitPanel`:

```
package menu;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import javax.swing.*;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class QuitPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{

     public Button yesKnop, noKnop;
     public JLabel label;
     public Tanks mainVenster;
     public QuitPanel quitPanel;

     public IPanel quit;


    public QuitPanel(Tanks mainVenster)
    {

         quit = new IPanel("/achtergronden/menu.jpg", mainVenster);

         int x = 95, width = 200, height = 50;

         label = new JLabel("ARE YOU SURE?");
         Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 25);
         label.setFont(font);
         label.setBounds(x+20, 400, width, height);

         yesKnop = new Button("/buttons/YES.png",x, 450, this);     
         noKnop = new Button("/buttons/NO.png",x, 525, this);

         this.add(quit);
         this.add(label);
         this.add(noKnop);
         this.add(yesKnop);

    }


     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if(ae.getSource() == noKnop)
            quit.switchPanel(mainVenster); //this is wrong
        else if(ae.getSource() == yesKnop)
            System.exit(0); 

    }

}
```

as you can see i extended the class with `JPanel` because when i tried to extend `IPanel` i got an error at `public HTPPanel(Tanks mainVenster)` that said
[image: the error]

when i open my quitPanel i get this:
[image: quitPanel when opened]

so i know there must be a part of my code correct, the only problem is the fact that my *background doesn't load* 
--> (`public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method)

the *question* is: how do i use the method i created in class nr 1 in class nr 2?

also, the *noButton* isn't working (yesButton is working fine)
--> (`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` method in )
--> also because of `public void switchPanel(Tanks toActivate)` i guess

thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, and there are two generalized approaches, composition and interhitence.

With composition, you push the code into a new class that your current solution then uses by creating and holding an instance of the code-holding class.

With inheritance, you create a class that your current solution extends, and put the code in a method in that parent class.  Then you have the "other" class extend the one that contains the desired code.

Generally, composition is easier to handle over time than inheritance; but, with time, you will recognize when inheritance is the better solution due to it's ability to leverage polymorphisim.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because when you're extending `IPanel`, you're expected to use at least one of the `super`'s constructors. In this case, there's one, so you'd have to use:

```
public IPanel(String backgroundPath, Tanks mainVenster)
```

*CORRECTION*

It isn't necessarily that you *need* to (it seems ideal to me), but in a constructor, one of the `superclass's` constructors need to be called with `super(...)`.

Meaning, if I had class `A` with its constructor:

```
public class A {
    public A(String name) {
    }
}
```

and class `B extends A`, I could do a few things:

```
public class B {
    // Option 1: Superclass's Constructor
    public B(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    // Option 2: Pass static value
    public B() {
        super("something here");
    }

    // Option 3: Use null
    public B() {
        super(null);
    }
}
```

No matter what, in the end, if your `superclass` only contains `constructors` with `parameters`, every `constructor` of the subclass will need to call `super(...)` to one of the `superclass's constructors`.

If you put a default `constructor` e.g.: `public A() {}` in your `superclass`, you won't need to call `super()` on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the default constructor without parameters to the IPanel class,
e.g.

```
public IPanel() { }
```

then you can use your parent class IPanel for extending.

Comment: this seems like a reasonable answer, but i don't really understand how i can call the constructor without the parameters i want...

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a constructor, the compiler is not going to create a constructor without parameters for you (you did this in your IPanel class).

```
public class A {
    public A(String str) { 
        //Compiler will not create a constructor without parameters.
    }
}
```

Reversed, if you don't specify a constructor, the compiler is going to create a constructor without parameters for you (you did this in your HTPPanel class).

```
public class A {
    //Compiler will create a constructor without parameters.
}
```

Now the thing is that in a class that extends some other class, the default constructor will call it's superclass constructor with no arguments.

```
public class A {
    public A(String str) {}
}

public class B extends A {}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(); //Compile error
    }
}
```

But also if you specify the constructor in class B, but do not add a call to it's superclass constructor, the compiler will automatically call the superclass constructor *without arguments*.

```
public class A {
    public A(String str) {}
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(int i) {}
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(); //Compile error
    }
}
```

In other words, you should either add a constructor with no parameters in your IPanel class, (or add a call to the super constructor with appropriate arguments), but I believe that's not what you want to do here.

Now, as for your other questions, it can be due to multiple reasons and it will always be a guess without full code. Also consider, that when you're going to extend the IPanel class with some Panel class, that if you want to override the `paintComponent` method in this panel and still draw the background, you should call `super.paintComponent(g);`, try to figure out *why*.